# Unable to get syntax correct on apoc.es.get or apoc.es.query call from Neo4j to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm having a hard time getting the syntax right on an `apoc.es.query` or an `apoc.es.get` for a nested field call into elasticsearch from my Neo4j database.

I'm running Neo4j 4.3.1 with ELK at 7.15.0.

I am trying to grab specific event IDs such as 4624 for user logons. Which is in `event.code: 4624` and/or `winlog.event_id: 4624`.

Here is what works:

```
CALL apoc.es.query("http://user:password@ipaddress:9200","logstash*","_doc","_source",{
  query: { match_all: {} }
})
YIELD value
UNWIND value.hits.hits AS hit
RETURN hit;
```

Here is what doesn't:

```
CALL apoc.es.query("http://user:password@ipaddress:9200","logstash*","_doc",null,
{ query: { match: { event.code: 4624}}})
YIELD value
UNWIND value.hits.hits AS hit
RETURN hit;
```

Or same thing with winlog:

```
CALL apoc.es.query("http://user:password@ipaddress:9200","logstash*","_doc",null,
{ query: { match: { winlog.event_id: 4624}}})
YIELD value
UNWIND value.hits.hits AS hit
RETURN hit;
```

No matter how I structure it, I either get a syntax error or zero results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I received the solution over on the Neo4j forums that I will re-post here. The syntax should be like the following:

```
CALL apoc.es.query("http://user:password@ipaddress:9200","logstash*","_doc",null,
{ query: { match: { `winlog.event_id`: 4624}}})
YIELD value
UNWIND value.hits.hits AS hit
RETURN hit;
```

Notice the back ticks (``) around winlog.event_id. This worked in my environment. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

In Elasticsearch `match` query is a standard for performing full-text search, but the data types of your fields doesn't seem textual. Perhaps you should use `term` query instead.

```
{ query: { term: { event.code: 4624 }}}
{ query: { term: { winlog.event_id: 4624}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michal. I ran the call with your suggestion but still encountered an error. Here is the syntax I used:
```
call apoc.es.query("http://user:password@ipaddress:9200","logstash-2021.09.23-000001","_doc",null,{ query: { term: { winlog.event_id: 4624 }})
YIELD value
UNWIND value.hits.hits AS hit
RETURN hit;
```
Here is the error I received:
```
Invalid input '{': expected "+" or "-" (line 1, column 127 (offset: 126))
"call apoc.es.get("http://user:password@ipaddress:9200","logstash-2021.09.23-000001","_doc",null,{ query: { term: { winlog.event_id: 4624 }})"
```

Comment: To be honest I don't have any knowledge of apoc and focused my answer on Elasticsearch query part.